# Node Socket Server Errror on nginx server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, nginx, server

I have created a socket for my messaging app which is working fine on the local server. Connection and Listeners are working properly.

But When I updated that on the server, Then not able to establish the connection.

I am using pm2 for running ports on nginx server.

This is how my configuration looks like here -

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```js
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /socket {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

PS: MY js code seems fine as that is working fine on local server so not adding here. I am assuming it's a problem from here with the configuration

Comment: Did you configure Nginx to listen both on port 3000 and on port 3001?

Comment: nginx 3000 is server my web and apis, Wanted to run socket on another port

Comment: Sure, but you also need to [listen on all ports](https://serverfault.com/q/655067/582608).